# Networkx drawing layout for multilayer or group

Tags: python, layout, networkx

I am going to draw a network with python3 and `networkx`moduel.

First of all, I am sorry I could not write any example code because I did not receive any raw data.

The network consists of 3 groups of nodes and a below attached is what I imagined.

It is a hand drawn.

[image]

I would like to refer any layout or tips to draw this kind of above.

I know `Multipartite Layout`https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/auto_examples/drawing/plot_multipartite_graph.html#multipartite-layout, however, I am not sure it is suitable for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multi-partite layout is going to put your nodes in rows/columns based on the partitions you specify, but it seems like what you want is to align your nodes so that the provided groups/partitions are clustered together and separated from the other groups/clusters. You can do this by making a position dictionary that you can pass to the `networkx` drawing functions. The example function below takes your graph, the name of the node attribute in your Graph object that specifies which group/partition each node belongs to (`partition_attr`), an optional list of partition names specifying the order you want to  display your groups/components left-to-right (`partition_order`) and the minimum space between nodes in different partitions (`epsilon`).

```
#%% Function to make position dicts by partition
def make_node_positions(graph,partition_attr,partition_order=None,epsilon=.5):
    if not partition_order:
        # get a list of all the partition names if not specified
        partition_order = list(set(dict(graph.nodes(data=partition_attr)).values()))
        
    # make position dict for each partition
    orig_partition_pos_dicts = {partition:nx.spring_layout(graph.subgraph([node for node,part in graph.nodes(data=partition_attr)
                                                                                      if part == partition]))
                                for partition in partition_order}
    
    # update the x coordinate in the position dicts so partitions
    # don't overlap and are in the specified order left-to-right
    final_pos_dict = orig_partition_pos_dicts[partition_order[0]]
    for i,partition in enumerate(partition_order[1:]):
        # get the largest x coordinate from the previous partition's nodes
        max_previous = max([x for x,y in final_pos_dict.values()])
        # get smallest x coordinate from this partition's nodes
        current_min = min([x for x,y in orig_partition_pos_dicts[partition].values()])
        # update the x coordinates for this partition to be at least epsilon units
        # to the right of the right-most node in the previous partition
        final_pos_dict.update({node:(pos[0]+max_previous+abs(current_min)+epsilon,pos[1])
                                               for node,pos in orig_partition_pos_dicts[partition].items()})
    return(final_pos_dict)
```

Now I've made a graph similar to your drawing and applied the function below

```
#%% Set up toy graph
import networkx as nx

# make the initial graphs
k5 = nx.complete_graph(5)
triangle=nx.from_edgelist([(5,6),(6,7),(5,7)])
single_node = nx.Graph()
single_node.add_node(8)

# edges to connect the components
extra_edges = [(3,5),(2,6),(5,8),(6,8),(7,8)]

# combine graphs and specify the original graphs
orig_graphs = {'k5':{'graph':k5,'color':'blue'},
               'triangle':{'graph':triangle,'color':'green'},
               'single_node':{'graph':single_node,'color':'red'}}
g = nx.Graph()
for g_name,g_val_dict in orig_graphs.items():
    # add the nodes from that graph and specify the partition and node colors
    g.add_nodes_from(g_val_dict['graph'].nodes,partition=g_name,color=g_val_dict['color'])
    if len(g_val_dict['graph'].edges) > 0:
        # if the graph has edges then add the edges
        g.add_edges_from(g_val_dict['graph'].edges,partition=g_name,color=g_val_dict['color'])
        
# add the extra edges to combine the graphs
g.add_edges_from(extra_edges,color='black')


#%% Draw graph #####
my_pos = make_node_positions(g,partition_attr='partition',partition_order=['k5','triangle','single_node'])
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g,my_pos,node_color=[c for n,c in g.nodes(data='color')])
nx.draw_networkx_labels(g,my_pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g,my_pos,edge_color=[c for u,v,c in g.edges(data='color')])
```

[image: graph with partition separated locations]